# Entt - Iterate over all the entities in Entt Entity Component System

Tags: c++, entity-component-system, entt

I am adding Entt Ecs to my project

I wonder while iterating throughout the registry with `Registry.each([&](auto EntityID)`

Is there any chance we can get EntityID as entt:null?

If there is then I can add guards.... And If yes then why would an entity be null

Answer (score 1):

No,

you can not get `entt::null` for your `EntityID`. The function `each` loops through the list of `entities` which only contain active entities.

you can find the implementation [here](https://entt.docsforge.com/master/api/entt/basic_registry/each/#Title)

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void each(Func func) const {
    if(free_list == null) {
        for(auto pos = entities.size(); pos; --pos) {
            func(entities[pos - 1]);
        }
    } else {
        for(auto pos = entities.size(); pos; --pos) {
            if(const auto entity = entities[pos - 1]; entity_traits::to_entity(entity) == (pos - 1)) {
                func(entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```